# How to mathematically/logically prove that everything in our "real" world is finite?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, infinity

Ok. This sounds like a kid question made when she/he first heard about "infinite". (But is that even bad?)

So, I'll give a lecture about (cardinals) infinite numbers for some 12-15 yo kids and I wish I could make a logical proof of the statement *"There are only finite-many stars in the universe"*; That is, some proof without using physics/chemical properties (like the quantizable property of the matter etc.).

For example (the following is some of what **I'm not looking for**):

> Affirmation: In a bottle of water there are only finite-many atoms
>
> Proof: The water is all composed by smaller parts (insert physics here) of fixed size greater then some $s\in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that there are infinite many atoms in the bottle, but that would implie that the size of the bottle is at least $\sum \limits _{i=1}^{\infty}i\cdot s$ wich do not converge for a finite number, but the bottle has a finite size; *contradiction!*

But how can I assume that the bottle is finite? This argument seems pretty vague when atoms in a bottle of water is changed by "stars in the universe". And I think that a proof using only logical arguments would be more interesting...

Was this clear enough?
I'd be glad if anyone could help me! And if this is duplicated, I'm sorry, I couldn't find something related.

Comment: The problem of the bottle and stuff  could painfully trick you down, as there are curves which can be revolved and get something (3 dimensional body) with infinite surface area yet finite volume...

Comment: We don't know if the Universe is finite or infinite, hence we don't know if there are a finite or infinite number of stars.

Comment: Mathematics/logic alone cannot *prove* anything about the real world. The statement "There are only finite-many stars in the universe" is probably false depending on your definition of Universe. If it's defined as only what we can observe then it's true, but the truthness of this depends our physical models for the universe and cannot be deduced from logic.

Comment: @Winther But isn't it clear that the question is open-endedly asking how one might prove some conclusions about finiteness in the real world (conclusions which should be stated precisely, of course), *from premises* (to be adduced by whichever brave soul answers the question)? That is how I interpret it, anyway.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley I strongly disagree: "some proof without using physics/chemical properties (like the quantizable property of the matter etc.)."

Comment: I know of nothing even approaching an argument that "infinity in the real universe" is logically impossible. A version of this question (in particular, changed to ask "**is there** an argument ...") could be appropriate for philosophy.stackexchange, but I don't think it fits here.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Oops, yes, I didn't see that bit! I now strongly disagree with myself, too. :)

Answer (score 2):

What is "our 'real' world"? If you're referring to the *physical* world, then it seems intuitive that you could not prove anything about it without assuming at least one *physical* premise (as Winther alluded to in the comments).